# How can I reduce the width of an area?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

At the moment I have this :

[image]

And I want to delimit the 3 elements to have something like this :

[image]

```
<th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat" data-date="2016-10-01">JOUR 1<br>samedi 1 octobre</th>
```

I tried to reduce the width of the fc-day-header class but that changed nothing.

I am very bad at css so I don't know what to do.

Have an idea ?

EDIT: html structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fc-axis fc-widget-header" style="width:18px"></th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat" data-date="2016-10-01" style="width:70%;">JOUR 1<br>samedi 1 octobre</th>
      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun" data-date="2016-10-02">JOUR 2<br>dimanche 2 octobre</th>
      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon" data-date="2016-10-03">JOUR 3<br>lundi 3 octobre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The html and the css are not mine, they are generated by full calendar.

I can modify them only by javascript.

Comment: Many ideas ... use 3 divs ... use 3 spans ... use 3 li .... don't use table .... use flexbox .... use float ... use inline-block .... Whitout seen enough code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Add a margin to your cells. For specific advice we need to see the css you have so far.

Comment: show us the html structure

Comment: Show us the initial `HTML` (before auto generation), your own `CSS` and the create script of `fullcalender()` (with options etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the border-spacing property to space out each cell.

https://jsfiddle.net/3xe5mzmx/

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fc-axis fc-widget-header" style="width:18px"></th>
      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat" data-date="2016-10-01">JOUR 1<br>samedi 1 octobre</th>
      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun" data-date="2016-10-02">JOUR 2<br>dimanche 2 octobre</th>
      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon" data-date="2016-10-03">JOUR 3<br>lundi 3 octobre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 15px 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 3 seperate `div`s, that use `margin-left` and `margin right`.

Comment: I can't do that, it's generated dynamically, and it's a calendar .. And it's not even mine it's full calendar.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov - How is anyone supposed to know that when you've posted no code and no details about what you're using?

Comment: What do you mean by "And it's not even mine it's full calendar."? Do you have access to the code? Edit: Okay I get you.